# Flagging upvoted but obsolete comments

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, comment-flags

While doing some research on [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), I flagged an [*upvoted* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript/8228308#comment-28139092), that corrected an answer, as obsolete. The entirety of the comment was subsequently edited into the answer and therefore the comment is obsolete by [Stack Overflow definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging):

> obsolete — **a comment that is no longer relevant because it has been
>   addressed by an edit to the post**, clarified by additional comments, or
>   contains no context because it references deleted content

My flag ended up being declined, so I raised a custom flag attempting to explain that the comment had been included in the post and was no longer needed and that flag was declined as well. This is a bit discouraging as I thought I was doing the right thing.

Is flagging upvoted comments discouraged?

Are there any other reasons why an *obsolete* comment would not be removed?

Comment: Moderators handle comment flags without context. If it isn't obvious from the comment in isolation that it is obsolete they might err on the safe side and decline. Use a custom flag in those cases, if that failed as well, come to meta ... now we wait for the mod ... I grab the popcorn...

Comment: A mod actually edited the post and rolled back his edit. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8228308/revisions. Was it after your flagging?

Comment: SO users tend to get attached to contributions that were found helpful by 25 other SO users.  That doesn't happen very often.  Technically you are correct, practically I wouldn't want to have to boogeyman job either.  Consider giving the mods a break, this comment is not harmful.

Comment: @HansPassant I am in no way trying to bash on the mods here, I appreciate all they do, which is why I am not asking for a specific reason as to why my flag was declined, just a general question about upvoted but now obsolete comments. :)  But, if comments are second class citizens, and they're obsolete, should we really be getting *attached* to them?

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ The mod actually added a link to the comment. He then rolled it back. The comment content was present earlier (which possibly is why you flagged it as obsolete).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You flagged a comment, and then when your flag was declined, chose to flag it again.

I initially declined it because generally such helpful comments are not obsolete.  Highly upvoted comments deserve their time, and corrective comments that are highly upvoted deserve attention.

You then flagged it again (while I was cleaning up other comments in the queue); this time, I went to the post, noted that the post didn't really obsolete the comment (for reasons I get into below), tried to fix it; was foiled, and just left things as they were.

It's a comment.  There are lots of things to worry about, but a singular comment doesn't have to be one of those things you reflag after your flag being declined a first time.

Incidentally, there are a lot of other comments on that question/answers that can be deleted and probably deserve flags.

The reason I didn't delete the comment is simple: Without it, the correction makes no sense. Who is "Guffa"?  I could change my name to Guffa, but that doesn't make me Guffa.

A better thing to do if you truly wanted the comment to go away (although, why? I can give you links to thousands of posts that truly need your help, not one upvoted comment), would be to appropriately link to the user's profile so they can be attributed correctly.

You'll note that I tried to do that; but apparently the software is smarter than I am.  Instead of worrying about it, I went back to handling other flags.

I'm also pleased to note the flag queue is down to zero, from over 800 when I started today. That's a happy feeling.

Comment: I truly do want to help, that's why I asked this question, as to not waste moderators time in the future with these types of flags.  I appreciate your response and respect your decision, thank you for taking the time to explain it. I won't flag those types of comments anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you wanted to link to but I've edited the post anyway. I hope it was for the better.

Comment: @5gon12eder: The added Correction block at the end is even more confusing, since the original post is no longer wrong. I think it's better to keep a comment a comment, or incorporate it into the post in a seemless manner.

Comment: @nhahtdh Well, I didn't *add* that block, I added a link to the user profile and I did make that block a quotation ([diff](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8228308/revisions)). Should I remove the block-quote again?

Comment: @5gon12eder: Sorry, I didn't check the revision carefully. I think that the post is better off without the comment added as-is, since it's confusing to future reader.

Comment: I've removed the the comment block inserted in the question. This was actually not required because the Op himself/herself addressed that comment via this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8228308/4 and clearly mentioned that in the edit description (with the words - *"updates stated by Guffa in comments"*). So, as @nhahtdh rightly observed, the post is better off without the revision which was already incorporated by the Op ages ago.

Comment: @Abhitalks: The original author rolls it back >:<

Comment: That's interesting @nhahtdh indeed -- "*I want this info in my answer. It is part of my answer now. If you think the comment might be obsolete, deal with it, stop editing my answer.*". Whoa!!

Comment: Who is "Guffa"? :)